# How to add animation to a view changing its height in react native?

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to increase and decrease the height of a rectangle depending on several conditions... The task is completed, however, I want to make the height changes smoothly and gradually.

How could I do that in react native while my CSS is dynamically changing?

```
 getBarStyle() {
    if (this.state.value < this.state.minValue) {
      return {
        height: 0
      };
    }
    let accurateHeight;
    accurateHeight = (this.state.value * (this.state.graphHeight - lineDiffValue);

    return {
      height: accurateHeight,
      transition: "height 2s"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
            <View style={[styles.rectangle, this.getBarStyle()]} />
        )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, create an `Animated.Value` with the starting value of the View.

```
constructor() {
  this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(50);
}
```

Then, create a function which will animated the height. The example below will animate from `50` to `100`.

```
startAnimation = () => {
  Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
    toValue: 100
  }).start();
}
```

Finally, pass your animated style to your View. You need to use `Animated.View`, not `View`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ height: this.animatedValue }} />
  )
}
```

Don't forget to `import { Animated } from 'react-native';`

Comment: Do not forget to call the function startAnimation since it will not call itself

Comment: I don't understand this as the accepted answer. I get the error: Style property 'height' is not supported by native animated module.

Comment: @CraigHowell Same

Comment: useNativeDriver: false

Comment: How about updating this answer for functional components ?

Comment: if you put this useNativeDriver: false, you will have performance visual issues. @AmmarIsmaeel

Answer (score 3):

## Error

```
<Animated.View style={{ height: this.animatedValue }} />
```

> error: Style property 'height' is not supported by native animated module.

As the React-Native documentation said, you can only animate non-layout properties. Transform property is supported so you can use transform.scaleY instead of changing the height :((

so..

## Try my solution

```
constructor(props: any)
{
    this.state.isDisplay = true;
    this.state.animatedView = new Animated.Value(100);
    this.state.animatedViewInterpolate = 
    this.state.animatedView.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 100], outputRange: ["0%", "100%"] });
    this.animateDuration = 500;
}

onPressDisplayView()
{
    if (this.state.isDisplay)
    {
        Animated.timing(this.state.animatedView, { toValue: 0, duration: this.animateDuration }).start(() => 
        { 
            this.setState({ isDisplay: false });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Animated.timing(this.state.animatedView, { toValue: 100, duration: this.animateDuration }).start(() => 
        {
            this.setState({ isDisplay: true }); 
        });
    }
}

render()
{
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Button onPress={() => {this.onPressDisplayView()}}>Display</Button>
            <View style={{ height: this.state.animatedViewInterpolate, backgroundColor: '#F00' }}>
                <Text>HelloWorld!</Text>
            </View>
        </View>);
}
```

1. use **interpolate**
2. I wrote this without running. maybe work or not :)